# Executing a function of an uncasted object

Tags: c#

I am implementing a web control that gets an object (as an argument) with a certain function -- lets call it DoStuff() -- the object can belong to different classes, which are all derived from an abstract class -- lets call it SuperClass -- this SuperClass does not have the DoStuff() method.

So my question is: Is there a way in C# to call a method of an Object on runtime if this method exists in the object without having to cast it to the derived classes.

Something like (I know this does not work but I think it expresses better what I would like to accomplish):

```
if(myObject.Functions["DoStuff"] != null){
    myObject.executeFunction("DoStuff");
}
```

Is this at all possible??

Comment: Is the object guaranteed to have that method?

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, the control can only be called if the class has the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with reflection, like:

```
uses System.Reflection

....

public void ExecuteMethod(object thing, string method)
{
   Type type = thing.GetType(); //gets the runtime type of the object
   MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod(method); // null if method not found
   mi.Invoke(thing, null); //invokes the method on the "thing" object,
                           //passing null arguments, and returns the result

}
```

However, in your scenario it would be better (if possible) to create an interface `IDoStuff` that will have `DoStuff` method, and make all classes that will be possibly called to do stuff implement it.
That way your code will be simpler and less prone to errors, like this:

```
public void ExecuteDoStuff(object thingy)
{
   if (thingy is IDoStuff)
      ((IDoStuff)thingy).DoStuff();
   else
      throw new Exception("thingy cannot do stuff");
}
```

Comment: I would also like the interface solution, however that is not possible, since I am only suppoused to mess around with the Control... so reflection is excatly what I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, in C# 4 you could write:

```
dynamic d = myObject;
d.DoStuff();
```

That will throw an exception if the `DoStuff()` method can't be bound, but the binding is only checked *at execution time.*

It's *relatively* tricky to find out whether or not that's going to work without just doing it - you could always catch the exception of course, but it's not ideal.

You could try to find it with reflection, but again I don't see that as an idea approach.

The bigger question is why the abstract class *doesn't* have the `DoStuff` method, at least as an abstract method. That would be a *far* better solution.

If only *some* of the subclasses have the `DoStuff` method, it would be better to put that into an interface:

```
public interface IStuffable
{
    void DoStuff();
}
```

Then make the appropriate subclasses implement `IStuffable`, and you can write:

```
IStuffable stuffable = myObject as IStuffable;
if (stuffable != null)
{
    stuffable.DoStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do so. I start with the recommended ones:

- Create an interface wich contains you `DoStuff()` method an implement it in all your classes. Then cast your object to that interface:

  ```
  interface IDoStuff {
      void DoStuff();
  }

  // call it on your object
  ((IDoStuff)object).DoStuff();
  ```
- Extend your baseclass to contain your `DoStuff()` Method (if possible)
- Use reflection to call the method:

  ```
  object.GetType().GetMethod("DoStuff").Invoke();
  ```